# Grouping data by MONTH on DATETIME column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, datetime

I have a table `Employee` which has the columns Id, Date of joining and Name

Date of joining is a `DATETIME` column.

I want to know how many users have joined in the month of October?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're just looking for October **regardless of the year**, then the easy way would be to just `COUNT` the records from that month:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfJoiners FROM Employee WHERE MONTH(DateOfJoining) = 10;
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfJoiners FROM Employee WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, DateOfJoining) = 10;
```

If you want to group by year, then you'll need a group by clause, otherwise October 2013, 2014, 2015 etc would just get grouped into one row:

```
SELECT 
  DATEPART(YEAR, DateOfJoining) AS YearOf Joining, 
  COUNT(*) AS NumberOfJoiners 
FROM Employee
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, DateOfJoining) = 10
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, DateOfJoining);
```

Comment: Given the date of asking, I'd say there's a third and most likely possibility: that we seek the count of users who joined **in October 2014**.